# error rspec visit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am testing a little thing to learn Rspec

I did like this :

```
feature "referral" do
    context "logged as an user for the first time" do
        let(:user) { create(:user) }
        before do
            login_user(user)
            visit 'fr/users/edit'
            save_and_open_page
        end
        it { should have_content "nombre d'invités : 0" }
    end
end
```

error :

```
ERROR : Failure/Error: visit 'fr/users/edit'
        ActionController::RoutingError:
        No route matches [GET] "/fr/fr/users/edit"
```

So I understood by this ERROR that "fr/" is concatenated with the path "fr/users/edit" so It's normal that it doesn't work.
Then I did like this

```
feature "referral" do
    context "logged as an user for the first time" do
        let(:user) { create(:user) }
        before do
            login_user(user)
            visit 'users/edit'
            save_and_open_page
        end
        it { should have_content "nombre d'invités : 0" }
    end
end
```

but then I have a weird error :

```
ERROR : Failure/Error: visit 'users/edit'
        ActionView::Template::Error:
        no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Please someone helps me :D

Update : see below the self answer I made

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error` indicates a bug in your view. Is that the whole error message?

Comment: @Stefan Yeah it's a bug in my view, I had to put .to_s to some integer so that rspec doesn't make an error. (it's was working when I did it manually)
Thak you very much !

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefan said, ActionView::Template::Error indicates a bug in the view

But even if it seams to work manually, Rspec can make error ( here for me, I needed to call the to_s method on some Integer I was printing in my view :)